Does Java Class Data Sharing (CDS) also archive classes in the "classpath"?
We are working on an application that runs the following java command:
java -classpath "C:/dir/sample1.jar; C:/dir/sample2.jar" example.class

I loaded classes to LoadedClasses.lst:
java -classpath "C:/dir/sample1.jar; C:/dir/sample2.jar" -XX:DumpLoadedClassList=LoadedClasses.1st example.class


I then dump the clases into an archive, SharedArchive.jsa:
java -classpath "C:/dir/sample1.jar; C:/dir/sample2.jar" -Xshare:dump -XX:SharedClassListFile=LoadedClasses.1st -XX:SharedArchiveFile=SharedArchive.jsa example.class

My question is: does the LoadedClasses.lst and SharedArchive.jsa contain the classes from the classpath "C:/dir/sample1.jar; C:/dir/sample2.jar" ? If not, how can I do so?
I ran the command:
java -classpath "C:/dir/sample1.jar; C:/dir/sample2.jar" -Xshare:auto -XX:SharedArchiveFile=SharedArchive.jsa example.class 

But it does not seem to load many of the classes (Sample1.jar, Sample2.jar) from the SharedArchive.jsa. It seems like it is still loading them from C:/dir/sample1.jar and C:/dir/sample2.jar

The first question is easy to answer; just open the LoadedClasses.1st file with a text editor and see yourself, which classes are contained. When you say “It seems like” the classes are still loaded from the jar file, what makes you think so? And why don’t you use an impartial tool, like logging the class loading, to find out for sure?

@Holger Thank you for the response! It's going through thousands of classes. I found out that most of the classes that were not getting archived were due to being pre-JDK-6, which is not supported by CDS. The problem is that it is jython.
